# Ruby what class gets a method when there is no explicit receiver?

Tags: ruby, methods

random question here.  I'm not sure if there's a term for this, but I'm wondering when you define a method without an explicit receiver, how can you know what class gets the method?  Is it whatever `self` is in that context?

`self` in the context of a class definition is the class being defined, and methods defined with an implicit receiver are bound to the class, which we see all the time.

But, if I define a method inside an instance method, that 'sub_method' is getting put on the outer class as well:

```
[12] pry(main)> class A
[12] pry(main)*   def my_method
[12] pry(main)*     puts self
[12] pry(main)*     def sub_method
[12] pry(main)*       puts self
[12] pry(main)*     end  
[12] pry(main)*   end  
[12] pry(main)* end  
=> :my_method
[13] pry(main)> a = A.new
=> #<A:0x007fa588181d40>
[14] pry(main)> a.my_method
#<A:0x007fa588181d40>
=> :sub_method
[15] pry(main)> a.sub_method
#<A:0x007fa588181d40>
=> nil
[16] pry(main)> A.instance_methods(false)
=> [:my_method, :sub_method]
```

Also at the top level scope, `self` is `main`, which is an instance of the `Object` class, but methods defined there are added to `Object`, not to `main`s singleton class, which is what I was expecting based on how I've seen other singleton methods work:

```
[21] pry(main)> def a.my_singleton
[21] pry(main)*   puts self
[21] pry(main)* end  
=> :my_singleton
[22] pry(main)> a.singleton_methods
=> [:my_singleton]
[23] pry(main)> A.instance_methods(false)
=> [:my_method, :sub_method]

[33] pry(main)> def why_object?
[33] pry(main)*   puts self
[33] pry(main)* end  
=> :why_object?
[34] pry(main)> why_object?
main
=> nil
[35] pry(main)> Object.instance_methods(false)
=> [:pry, :__binding__, :my_method, :sub_method, :why_object?]
```

What is going on here, is there a rule to this or are there just these few cases to know about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three implicit contexts in Ruby.

The most well-known is `self`, the current object and the default receiver.

The second well-known is the scope used for constant lookup. Broadly speaking, constant lookup is "lexically outward, then upward by inheritance", but there are many nuances. The Ruby maintainers call this context *cref*.

What you are asking about, is [the third context, sometimes called the *default definee*](http://yugui.jp/articles/846). Usually, the default definee is the **nearest lexically enclosing module**. But, you already found one exception: at the top-level, the default definee is actually `Object` (plus, the default *visibility* is `private`). `instance_eval` changes both `self` (to the receiver of the `instance_eval` message) and the *default definee* (to the receiver's *singleton class*). `class_eval` changes both to the receiver.

Comment: And before you start hunting it down: the article the author of that blog post mentioned about the third implicit context, never got written, unfortunately.

Comment: And for those who don't know her: Yugui was the Release Manager for Ruby 1.9, and she was responsible for many of the improvements in the Ruby design, development, maintenance, and release processes that we have so gotten used to that we sometimes forget about the bad old days of Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're confusing "receiver" as in "receiver of messages" which is what people usually mean by the term and "receiver" as in "destination context for any methods defined".

Calling `def` inside a method is allowed by the syntax but unorthodox in terms of style. The Ruby way of doing this is using [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) where you have more control over where that method goes. Think of `def` as a simple way of defining methods, but where the context is a little slippery. If called in a class context it defines an instance method. If called inside an instance method it defines another instance method.

Even better is to wrap that method up in a module you can later `include` or `extend` something with as you see fit.

Defining methods at the top-level scope, on `main`, means you want them universally available. The best way to do that is to force them into Object. This is why defining methods in that context can get messy in a hurry so it's not recommended for anything other than trivial programs.

Comment: Yea I guess I was referring to receiver incorrectly, and I know that all of the things up there are ugly and should never be done; I guess I was trying to understand whether the default class that a method belongs to when nothing is specified has anything to do with what `self` is where it's defined.

Comment: When making method calls the context is usually predictable, `self` doesn't change in Ruby as `this` does in JavaScript. When using `def` there's a few simple rules for where the methods go, but it's only really intended to be used on `main` or inside `class` or `module` directly.