# Why am I able to call the class method as if it were an instance method here?

Tags: sql, ruby, metaprogramming

I was looking through this example:

```
class SQLObject
  def self.columns
    return @columns if @columns
    columns = DBConnection.execute2(<<-SQL).first
      SELECT
        "#{table_name}".*
      FROM
        "#{table_name}"
      LIMIT
        0
    SQL
    columns.map!(&:to_sym)
    @columns = columns
  end

  def self.table_name
    @table_name ||= self.name.underscore.pluralize
  end

  def insert
    column_symbols = self.class.columns.drop(1)
    column_names = column_symbols.map(&:to_s).join(", ")
    question_marks = (['?'] * column_symbols.count).join(", ")
    DBConnection.execute(<<-SQL, *attribute_values)
      INSERT INTO
        #{self.class.table_name} (#{column_names})
      VALUES
        (#{question_marks})
    SQL
    self.id = DBConnection.last_insert_row_id
  end
end
```

And I was confused as to why it's ok to call the table_name method in the "self.columns" method as if it were an instance method. Isn't the "table_name" method a class method? Hence, shouldn't it be called  as "self.class.table_name" in the "self.columns" method as well?

Comment: Ah just a thought, maybe this is the answer. Is it because I'm calling a class method from within another class method??

Comment: When addressing problems like this one the value of `self` at different points in your code is key. It therefore may be helpful to salt your code with statements such as `puts "self=#{self}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inside an abstract class, the `self` refers to the proper class, not the object. That's why you can access the method without explicitly telling `self`

Comment: So just to clarify, if I were using this with a "Cat" object and a "cats" table, is the object the instance of a "Cat"? And is the proper class the "Cat" class itself?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you be more clear, please?

Comment: So I can understand why they used "self.class.table_name" in the insert method; from my understanding, it's because "table_name" is a class method and not an instance method. And is the idea that when you're calling a class method from within another, you can omit the explicit self receiver?? When I call a class method from within another, does the program somehow know that I am referring to self as the receiver?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because you are in an instance method context, self would refer to the object, not the class. Since in an class method there's no instance, self refers to the class itself, so there's no need to say self

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `self` is the implicit receiver in Ruby. If you leave it out, the message will be sent to `self`. In other words, it is *never* necessary to say `self.foo` in a message send, because `foo` is *always* implicitly the same as `self.foo`.

Long answer: there is no such thing as a "*class method*" in Ruby. What you call a "*class method*" is actually nothing but a *singleton method* defined on an object which just happens to be an instance of the class `Class`.

Actually, there are no *singleton methods* in Ruby, either. A *singleton method* is really nothing but a regular old *instance method* which is defined on the *singleton class* of an object.

[Note: This is not to say that you should not use those terms. Saying "class method" is clearly simpler and communicates intent better than "instance method of the singleton class of an object of class `Class`". Also, note that there are methods such as [`Object#singleton_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_methods). Those terms clearly exist in the Ruby *Community*, but it is important to understand that these concepts *do not* exist in the Ruby *Language*. They are a tool for communication, not an actual Ruby concept.]

The *singleton class* is a class that is associated with an individual object. Each object has exactly *one* singleton class and that object is the *only* instance (the "singleton instance", hence the name) of its singleton class.

In fact, the inheritance hierarchy of an object *always* starts with its singleton class, i.e. the *class pointer* of an object always points to its singleton class, and the singleton class's *superclass pointer* then points to the class that created this object. You just don't see the singleton class in the inheritance chain, because methods like [`Object#class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-class) "skip over" the singleton class when calculating the inheritance chain. It *is*, however, always used during method lookup.

In fact, method lookup is actually very simple (the only exception is [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend), which I am going to ignore for this explanation):

1. Dereference the receiver's *class pointer*.
2. If that class's method table has a method by the name of the message, invoke it. STOP.
3. If not, dereference the class's *superclass pointer*.
4. GOTO #2.
5. If you reach a class that doesn't have a superclass, restart the algorithm with the message [`method_missing(original_message_name, ...)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing), unless the message name is already `method_missing`, in which case raise a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html).

So, it all comes down to two questions:

- When defining a method, *which class (or module)* are you defining it in?
- When sending a message, *which object* are you sending the message to?

When you *define* a method using `def foo.bar`, Ruby will first evaluate the expression `foo` and then define a method `bar` on the resulting object's singleton class (the *definee*). If you don't provide `foo`, i.e. you just say `def bar`, then `bar` is defined on the [*default definee*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39455461/2988), which is a little bit of a tricky concept. Normally, it is the closest lexically enclosing module definition. If there is no enclosing module definition, i.e. you are at the top-level, the default definee is [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html) and the method visibility is [`private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private).

When you *send* a message using `foo.bar`, Ruby will first evaluate the expression `foo` and then send the message `bar` to the resulting object (the *receiver*). If you don't provide `foo`, i.e. if you just say `bar`, then the *default receiver* is `self`.

Which brings us to the next question:

- What is `self`?

Within a method definition body, `self` is the receiver of the message send that led to the invocation of this method. So, if you send the message `foo.bar`, then any reference to `self` in the definition of the method `bar` will, during this one execution of the method, evaluate to `foo`.

Within a module or class definition body, `self` is the class or method itself. (That is why defining a <strike>singleton method</strike> instance method of the singleton class using `def self.bar` works in a module or class definition body.)

Within a block or lambda literal, `self` is lexically captured, i.e. it is whatever `self` is at the point where the block or lambda literal is written. *However*, there are a couple of methods which change how `self` is evaluated, most notably the [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), [`BasicObject#instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec), [`Module#module_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_eval), [`Module#module_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_exec), [`Module#class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval), [`Module#class_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_exec), … family of methods.

If you are always aware of the answers to those three questions (where am I defining a method, what is the receiver of a method call, what is `self`) at any point in your code, then you have basically understood the most important parts of Ruby.

So, to put it all together:

At the point where you are defining the method using `def self.columns`, we are in a class definition body, so `self` refers to the class object itself (`SQLObject`).

The syntax `def foo.bar` defines a method `bar` on the singleton class of `foo`. In this case, you define the method `columns` on the singleton class of `SQLObject`. This means that the object `SQLObject` is the only object in the universe that will respond to the message `columns`.

Both of these also apply to the definition of `self.table_name`.

Inside of the method body of `self.columns`, `self` will dynamically refer to whatever the receiver is.

When you send the message `columns` to `SQLObject`, i.e. you write `SQLObject.columns`, then inside the body of the `SQLObject::columns` method, the receiver (i.e. `self`) will be set to `SQLObject`. (In this case, the receiver will always be `SQLObject`, since this is a method of a singleton class.)

So, inside the method body of `self.columns`, when you write the message send `table_name`, this is a message send with an implicit receiver. Since the implicit receiver is `self`, this is equivalent to `self.table_name`. `self` at this point is bound to `SQLObject`, so this is equivalent to `SQLObject.table_name`. In other words, the message is sent to `SQLObject`.

Now, per the algorithm I outlined above, the method lookup first retrieves the class pointer from `SQLObject`. As mentioned, the class pointer always points to the singleton class. So, we look inside the singleton class of `SQLObject` to see if we find a method named `table_name`, and we do!

Method lookup is finished, everything works.